# Case sensitivity and database projects

Tags: sql-server, database-project

I created a schema in our SQL Server 2012 database called `[Auth]`. Then tables and triggers were created as well. Later I was informed that the schema naming standard is lowercase, so it should be `[auth]`. I renamed the schema in the database project, and all related references. However, the Schema Compare feature doesn't detect the difference, and isn't renaming the schema.

This affects our Entity Framework objects, as they *should* be `'auth'`.

Is there a way to make the database project see a case change as a change, and update the database?

Answer (score 14):

There is an option in the project settings called "Validate Casing on Identifiers" which according to the documentation shall detect difference in case. However, it only seems to be relevant if you select a case sensitive collation in the Database Settings of your project.

[image]

Once I selected SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS I was able to detect the changes in a schema name and it scripts the DROP/CREATE schema as expected:

[image]

Comment: This is not picking up case sensitive column name changes.  Do you know how to do that?

Comment: I was have a same problem. But my fields was in cyrrilic. I changed Database collation to `SQL_Latin1_Generel_CP1251_CS_AS` but it's not helped me. After i changed back to `SQL_Latin1_Generel_CP1_CS_AS` and it's works.