# Visual Studio Schema compare issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, schema-compare

In Visual Studio i changed a field name in data base project.

```
IdInInGeo -> IdInIngeo
```

After i do Schema compare but it's not recognized any changes in this table.
In Schema compares's Options i can't find a any settings about fields register (maybe because my english is weak).
How to make that Schema compare see fields name's changes like in my case? Any advises?

Comment: I have noticed that sometimes DataTools needs a small budge. Save your project, restart Visual Studio and repeat the schema compare. If you want to have a look at the compare settings, when in the schema compare screen click the small gear button at the top.

Comment: @MarcelN. I tried restart VS, after repeated Schema Compare but get same result. I found a Options button but can't find any settings inside for solve my problem (if this settings exists).

Comment: Maybe this will help out?

[Stackoverflow-Thread][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17203916/case-sensitivity-and-database-projects

Comment: Even with "Validate casing on identifiers" and a database collation of `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` (as suggested in the referenced question), schema compare is not picking up column name case changes for me.

Answer (score 3):

It happened to me one time. I could fix it using the following steps:

- Go to your database's **Project Settings**
- Tick right the checkbox entitled "Validate Casing on Identifiers"
- Click on the button "Database Settings"
- Under the "Data Collation" list, select: `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS`
- Click **OK**

Doing so would most probably allow you to detect changes in schema names.

Do note that a one-character difference in the collation may lead to different results. For example, `CI` means *case-insensitive*, whereas changing it to `CS` makes it *case-sensitive*.

Hope this helps.

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment when I started the bounty, this approach (mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/17204187/892313) did not work for me. That is why I placed the bounty.

Comment: I see. By default, columns inherit the collation of the database. Can you please tell what's the collation of the columns?

Comment: By the way, I see your comment there and found that you're using `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` rather than `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS`

Comment: I missed that one character difference between what you suggested and what I had tried. Your answer does work. If you edit your answer, I will reverse the down-vote to an up-vote.

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked. But what shall I edit in my answer? You mean to mention the one-character difference?

Comment: The content of the edit is not that important, although highlighting that one character difference is probably good. The issue is that I can't change my vote unless the answer has changed. So that's why I want you to make an edit.

Comment: @BrianDiggs - the last vowel of General of the example should be a vice e.